# Thunderbird just deleted all my past mails

Tags: data-recovery, thunderbird

I have configured Thunderbird to synchronize for mails for last 90 days. It has gone ahead and deleted older mails from my server in GMAIL.

I also used the compact option.

I also configured the retention policy to be 90 days.

What can I do to get them back ?

Comment: When you login to your Gmail account, are they not in the Trash? https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#trash

Comment: @spikey_richie No they are not. What do I do ?

Comment: Were you using POP mail download or IMAP synchronization?

Comment: @user1686 Gmail. so I guess IMAP.

Comment: did you look also in the "All mail" folder? For En, https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#all

Comment: @Andra Yup. They are not there.

Answer (score 0):

> **What can I do to get them back?**

### Gmail

Gmail says

> When you delete a message, it stays in your Bin for 30 days. After that time, it will be permanently deleted from your account and it won't be possible to recover it.

So if your Gmail Bin is empty, Gmail probably can't help.

---

### Thunderbird

Even for IMAP servers, Thunderbird has a habit of storing messages locally. You might be able to recover some older email by turning off your PC, and using recovery tools on the hard drive. For example by removing the hard drive, duplicating the hard drive at low level (to include duplication of unused space), connecting it (or better the duplicate) to another computer (ideally read-only) and running data recovery software.

It's been several years since I did this kind of recovery. I recall Thunderbird's file storage was basically one of the common ones (mbox etc) and so the mail is essentially stored as plain text grouped in data files.

This will be significant work but hard drives are cheap so there's nothing to lose by duplicating your existing hard drive (perhaps to two duplicate new drives) and working on recovery at your leisure.

---

E.g. In somewhere like  `%APPDATA%\Thunderbird\Profiles\1a2c3c4d5e6f.default\ImapMail\ABCD\`
 there may be some files such as

```
INBOX
INBOX.msf
foldername
foldername.msf
```

Ignore the MSF files, the files without filename extensions can be viewed in a text editor - obviously you should use a text viewer or an editor that can be forced to open files read-only. You'll see plain text mail headers (in the style of RFC822 headers and whatever RFCs superseded it) followed by plain text contents and/or something like HTML or BASE64 encoded rich-text message content. Messages are typically separated by a blank line followed by a line starting "From".

Since I love coding, I spent many a happy hour writing code to parse subject-lines, dates and sender names from these files but you can probably fairly easily import the files wholesale and verbatim into another email installation.

A data recovery tool will be able to resurrect deleted mail files, older versions of these files and fragments of older versions of these files. These resurrected items may allow you to piece together older mail messages that Thunderbird has been used to view at some time in the past - regardless of whether they are nominally stored on an IMAP server.

Anecdotally, I have on my desk in front of me a hard-disk from an IMAP server that failed. Some mail was not available on the latest backups (useful things backups) but I recovered the missing mail from Thunderbird on a desktop client PC so never needed to examine the old hard disk of the server to see if the server failure was due to the HDD failing. So I know IMAP mail can be recovered from a local Thunderbird IMAP client even though you might expect it to not cache or store mail locally.

Comment: This isn't that helpful to me. I don't mean to sound glib, but what you are saying means that they are completely deleted and there is no sensible way of getting them back.